# Remove null bytes when use Memory Mapped File

Tags: c#, null, byte

I used 4 threads to write data to a file. Each thread uses MMF to write a part of a file.
When I open the file with Notpad++ which always displays null byte between part of the file.

Thread 1 writes 1
Thread 2 writes 12
Thread 3 writes 123
Thread 4 writes 1234

The result will be like this: **1Nul12Nul123Nul1234Nul**

MMF requires 2 bytes to write "1" character, but actually "1" character is only one byte.

If I set 1 byte to MMF it will throw: **There are not enough bytes remaining in the accessor to write at this position.**

How to remove these null bytes ?

**Update code:**
I use only 2 threads for easier look.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        File.Delete(@"C:\abc.txt");

        CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = tokenSource.Token;

        // Write data to file using MMF.
        Task<int>[] tasks = new Task<int>[2];
        tasks[0] = new Task<int>(() => F1(0, 2, "1", cancellationToken), cancellationToken);
        tasks[1] = new Task<int>(() => F2(2,4, "12", cancellationToken), cancellationToken);

        // Create MMF File.
        MemoryMappedFileSecurity CustomSecurity = new MemoryMappedFileSecurity();

        MemoryMappedFile MemoryMapped = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(

               new FileStream(@"C:\abc.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate),
               "MapAbcFile",// Name

               20,                                    // Size

               MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite,               // Access type

               null,                          // You can customize the security

               HandleInheritability.None
               , false);              // Inherit to child process   



        try
        {
            ParallelOptions op = new ParallelOptions();
            op.CancellationToken = tokenSource.Token;
            Parallel.ForEach(tasks, op, t =>
            {
                try
                {
                    t.Start();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    tokenSource.Cancel();
                }

            });

            // Wait for all the tasks to finish.
            Task.WaitAll(tasks, cancellationToken);

            Console.WriteLine("Done!");
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cancelled!");
        }
        catch (AggregateException ae)
        {
            //tokenSource.Cancel();

            Console.WriteLine("AggregateException!");
            // Assume we know what's going on with this particular exception.
            // Rethrow anything else. AggregateException.Handle provides
            // another way to express this. See later example.
            foreach (var ie in ae.InnerExceptions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ie.Message);
            }
        }

        MemoryMapped.Dispose();

    }

    private static int F1(long offset, long size, string firstName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("ManagedThreadId(F1): {0} - {1}", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()));
        MemoryMappedFile MemoryMapped = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("MapAbcFile");
        MemoryMappedViewAccessor WriteFirstPart = MemoryMapped.CreateViewAccessor(offset, size, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);
        int i = 0;

        foreach (char item in firstName.ToCharArray())
        {
            WriteFirstPart.Write(i, item);
            i++;
        }

        WriteFirstPart.Dispose();
        return 1;
    }
    private static int F2(long offset, long size, string lastName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("ManagedThreadId(F2): {0} - {1}", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()));

        MemoryMappedFile MemoryMapped = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("MapAbcFile");
        MemoryMappedViewAccessor WriteFirstPart = MemoryMapped.CreateViewAccessor(offset, size, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);
        int i = 0;
        foreach (char item in lastName.ToCharArray())
        {
            WriteFirstPart.Write(i, item);
            i++;
        }
        WriteFirstPart.Dispose();

        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please show us the code you used to write the bytes?

Comment: `Do you have any idea?` is not a real question.  Besides that there is no question here.

Comment: Thanks Dan-o. I updated my question and code.

Comment: Don't remove them. Keep them. Or encode as UTF8. Or do you still think that English is the only language in the world and so ASCII can encode all text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is here:

> but actually "1" character is only one byte.

Whereas, a [`Char`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is actually defined as:

> Represents a character as a UTF-16 code unit.

UTF-16 code units take up *two* bytes.

If you want a `1` to only take up one byte, then you need to use something from the [`System.Text.Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to use say ASCII or UTF-8, or some other encoding where the character `1` takes up one byte. E.g.

```
foreach (byte item in System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(firstName))
{
    WriteFirstPart.Write(i, item);
    i++;
}
```